# Relay specs Question

Tags: relay

Can anyone explain to me why there are 2 maximum voltages/amperage for both AC and DC like  below ?

10A 250VAC   10A 125VAC

10A 30VDC    10A 28VDC

I was thinking that the one on the left is for normally open and the one on the right for normally closed ?

[image]

Comment: Can you upload a picture?. One will be european and one US/UL I guess.

Comment: Check edit pls.

Comment: i never heard of european / US DC voltages ?!

Comment: My guess is that these are voltages that are common in the application of these relays, so the ratings are specified at those points.  DC ratings are much lower because AC voltage crosses zero and extinguishes arcing, where DC arcs at similar voltages can persist causing much more rapid wear-out of the contacts.

Comment: Yes that I know, but why different DC voltages ?

Comment: Good question good question

Comment: The  c-"reverse R"U-US denote it has been evaluated to Canadian and US standards. Theses have standard values for some voltages, currents and types of loads. This example is a bit mixed up but its possible the right side values are for these UL ratings... The IEC versions may be different. Also note that some values might be for resistive loads, tungsten and others for inductive. The only way to know is to get the datasheet

Comment: This is its datasheet http://songle.com/pdf/2008961512231004.pdf

Comment: The Max. Allowable Voltage for dc is 110VDC O_o !?!

Comment: @Darren There is no max current spec for 110VDC, and it probably meets no safety agency test. Maybe in reality good for 100s of mA resistive ONLY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NC vs NO is is usually a different current at the same voltage (if the ratings are, in fact different).

More likely the differences you cite would refer to compliance with different safety agencies.

For example, this one:

[image]

Should not be used at more than 125VAC if you need compliance with Canadian and US safety requirements-- the cURus component registration. The other rating refers to other safety agencies.

Comment: Lol I picked the same one by chance.

Comment: Yeh :), the DC is my main concern. 30v and 28v. what difference would it make as long as your not using your country AC

Comment: Use the 28V rating in the US/Canada because that is where it was tested (to cURus standards) to not cause a fire. It may not make 100% sense, but this is CYA sometimes rather than EE.

Comment: Ahh, so CQC saftey limits are 250vAC or 30vDC and cURus safety limits are 125VAC or 28VDC ?

Comment: So in other words the max limit for DC is 30V, but just to be safer the max limit is 28V ?

Comment: Yes, that max DC voltage *and* max current. Rules for testing vary somewhat.

Comment: Reading the dAta sheet shows that the TUV testing allows up to 30vdc, while the ul/cul testing rates it for 28vdc. The ccc testing, however, allows a much higher voltage. So this answer is correct as to why there are different ratings printed on the relay.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about the compliance thing mentioned here however mechanical relays have different AC and DC ratings - this is standard! Now why... When the relay opens there will be an arc between the contacts.

If you are running AC (say 50Hz) the current goes down to 0A A 100 times per second, after this happened once the arc is gone. When you run DC there is no interruption to the current flow so the arc eats away on the contacts for longer. This is why the DC rating is always much lower.